# `M-! enter shell command enter` in org mode does not insert output in current buffer

Tags: org-mode, shell

When I run `M-! enter shell command enter` in org mode, I expect the output to be inserted into the buffer I have active.

Instead, emacs opens a second buffer (splitting the window in two) and inserts the output there. How can I make it insert the result in the buffer I am working?

Answer (score 4):

This is the normal behaviour for `shell-command`.

[If you want the output inserted into the current buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Single-Shell.html#Single-Shell), you must supply an argument (like `C-u M-!`).

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by typing `C-u M-! command RET`.  Checking the help on `M-!` explains why it works.

```
M-! runs the command shell-command, which is an interactive compiled
Lisp function in `simple.el'.

It is bound to s-L, M-!, <menu-bar> <tools> <shell>.

(shell-command COMMAND &optional OUTPUT-BUFFER ERROR-BUFFER)

Execute string COMMAND in inferior shell; display output, if any.
With prefix argument, insert the COMMAND's output at point.
```